# Is there a way to defocus fields in CDialog of VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, lost-focus, cdialog

When I make a dialog using CDialog project of VC++,
I can not defocus any field on this dialog(CDialog).
What I want to do is how some field can be defocused
when I clicked the outside of this field with mouse.

Thanks for any advice and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only obvious question: WHY? Why do you want to de-focus from a control, and (possibly) not give focus to any control? Some control within the dialog should have a keyboard focus!

You can however, make a textbox, which would be outside the visible area of dialog, and `SetFocus` on that control, whenever you get `WM_MOUSE*` message(s) on the `CDialog`.

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case, I have 6 tabs which has each dialog. When I change tab and see another tab, the previous input focus is still alive. So I want to know how to defocus input field. Is this case, how can we usaully control this problem?

Comment: According to the idea above, I have set focus static string like below.
OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_LABEL)->SetFocus();